# How to Host a React/Node Web Application on a server

Tags: sql-server, windows, reactjs, express, server

sorry for the broad question. I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction. I've created a Mssql/Express/React/Node web application and hosted it on Heroku. The problem is that I cannot connect to the company mssql database through the firewall.

Another option is for me to host the web application through a company server. Does anyone know how I would go about doing this? Would I just set up a windows service to start the application on start up? After its started how do I point a domain name to the application so it can be accessed online?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is a networking problem that may fare better on https://serverfault.com. If you host the server on a computer in your company's LAN, you'll need to configure your company's firewall and router so network requests are routed to the server on your computer. If misconfigured, this could open you up to some network attacks, and I don't think IT will be happy with that. I'm not sure how your company's network is set up, but on a more basic home network, this would entail going into your router/modem configuration and forwarding, say, requests on port 80, to your computer.

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could also also set up a VPN to connect to the database on the company LAN.

Comment: Thanks for the link i'll check it out. I'm going to work with IT on the server config but they don't seem know much about hosting web apps on a server and i've only used online services like Heroku, Digital Ocean, and aws in the past.